# Automapper Source Code Not Compiling

Tags: automapper

I've downloaded the latest code for `Automapper` on [Github](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper), but it won't compile.  When I look at the `Automapper's` project's references in the `Core` folder, it's empty.  How can this be?  I need to add the `Automapper's` projects to my solution - not allowed to reference the .dll, unfortunately.  What should I do? Is this because it's strongly named?

No references, so won't compile.

[image]

Comment: I feel a tumbleweed badge approaching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As best as I can tell, `AutoMapper` targets multiple platforms (I don't need this), so it references `.NET Portable Subset` to achieve this. I removed this reference and replaced it with the standard assembly references.  The project now compiles and I'm using it in my solution